# evasive module in apache error: "Can't locate API module structure `evasive24_module'"

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-evasive

I wanted to protect my Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) server in CentoOS 7 from DDOS attacks so after searching for some alternatives I found this [page](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/). They go through the installation of the modules evasive and security pretty easy. So I started first by installing the modules:

```
# yum update && yum install mod_security mod_evasive
```

Then, I added this two lines to my config file:

```
LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive24.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
```

and now that I try to start my server I get the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 375 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf: Can't locate API module structure `evasive24_module' in file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_evasive24.so: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_evasive24.so: undefined symbol: evasive24_module
```

Have anybody had this similar problem? Any tips or ideas of how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this bug report from RedHat :

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1232360

> Package mod_evasive-1.10.1-22.el7, should fix your issue, was pushed to the Fedora EPEL 7 testing repository. Update it with:
>
> ## su -c 'yum update --enablerepo=epel-testing mod_evasive-1.10.1-22.el7'

Comment: Very nice response! Thank you it was so helpful!